# Excel macro formula for calaculating numbers with letters

Tags: excel, vba

How do we calculate sum of associated numbers with letters in excel?
Data is mentioned below.
I have an assigned some value to each letter.

`"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"`

And their values respectively:

`1,2,3,4,5,8,3,5,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,1,2,3,4,6,6,6,5,1,7`

If i enter any word in the excel, it must returns single digit.

For example- the sum of the word "google" is (3+7+7+3+3+5)=28=10=1 final result.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Why would the sum of 1, 2, 5, 1 and 9 be 9?  And what do you mean "and so on" - I can't see any relationship between the letters you supplied and their corresponding values, so how do we know what values should be associated with other letters?

Comment: I was thinking you could use named values (same as named ranges, except they reference a static value) but you can't use `C` or `R` as a name and possibly some other letters to.  You could then use `=SUM(A,B,D,H)` to return 13.

Comment: I have an assigned some value to each letter. 
"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"; and their values
1,2,3,4,5,8,3,5,1,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,1,2,3,4,6,6,6,5,1,7 respectively.

If i enter any word in the excel, it must returns single digit.

For example- the sum of the word "google" is (3+7+7+3+3+5)=28=10=1 final result.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to a module:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print SumChars("ABCd")
End Sub

Public Function SumChars(strInput As String) As Double
    Dim arrChar(), arrVals()
    arrChar = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")
    arrVals = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 3, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 1, 7)

    Dim dblSum As Double
    dblSum = 0

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        For j = LBound(arrChar) To UBound(arrChar)
            If UCase(arrChar(j)) = UCase(Mid(strInput, i, 1)) Then
                dblSum = dblSum + arrVals(j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Do While Len(CStr(dblSum)) > 1
        dblSum = DigitSum(dblSum)
    Loop
    SumChars = dblSum
End Function

Private Function DigitSum(dblValue As Double) As Double
    Dim i As Integer, dblSum As Double

    For i = 1 To Len(CStr(dblValue))
        dblSum = dblSum + Mid(CStr(dblValue), i, 1)
    Next i

    DigitSum = dblSum
End Function
```

And you can use `=SumChars("ABC")` in any cell.
To make it case sensitive you need to remove the `UCase`

```
If arrChar(j) = Mid(strInput, i, 1) Then
```

Comment: The question is too broad - but I like your answer... Only thing is you don't do OP's final step of convert 28 to 1 the `google` example. Eg. 28= 1 because `2+8=10` and `1+0=1`. OP wants numerology calculator.

Comment: Its working. But if i enter some word like "wwwwwwwww", it returns 54,further it has to return 9.

Comment: My bad didn't see that. I updated my answer. @RobinMackenzie but you are right obviously the question is too broad. I promise to improve.

Comment: Can i pass cell number instead of word?

Comment: No worries @Peh. Nice answer anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

Put the letters into an array and their corresponsing values into an array, then loop through the array until you hit the required letter and return its value from the linked numbers array.

```
Function LetterValues(letter As Variant)

Dim letters() As Variant, numbers() As Variant

letters = Array("A", "B", "C")
numbers = Array(1, 2, 3)

For x = 0 To UBound(letters)
    If letters(x) = letter Then
        LetterValues = numbers(x)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next x

End Function

Sub TestFunction()

Dim result As Variant

result = LetterValues("A")

End Sub
```

You could use this in a sub, or as a [User Defined Function](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/user-defined-function.html) by placing it in a module.

This example returns the value of a letter but you could easily modify it to return a whole word.